# How do I calculate the Minkowski Difference between two AABBs (with no vector math)?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, geometry, collision-detection

I'm implementing the [second version of my collision detection library](https://github.com/kikito/bump.lua/tree/2.0). This particular library should deal with axis-aligned boxes (AABBs). I'd like to start tracking fast-moving boxes on this version. I think calculating the Minkowski Difference between the two would be a good starting point for that.

When I say Minkowsky Difference I mean the geometric operation described in [Collision detection for Dummies](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/#attachment_485).

The catch is: The process and algorithm described there is very generic. It uses fairly advanced vector math to calculate the MD of any two polygons.

In my case I have AABBs. Given their numerical simplicity, the library so far has not needed a Vector concept - for example, I have not needed to compute a single dot product. I'd like it to stay that way if at all possible.

So my question is:

**Given two AABBs by their top,left,width and height (`{t1,l1,w1,h1}` and `{t2,l2,w2,h2}`), how do I calculate their MD, (without getting vector math if possible)?**

Just by playing with the widget on Collision detection for Dummies, I'm almost certain that the MD width will be a box of width `w1+w2` and height `h1+h2`. But I have no idea about how to calculate its top or left corner.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Minkowski difference for two axes-aligned rectangles {t1, l1, w1, h1} and {t2, l2, w2, h2} is itself an axes-aligned rectangle:

```
l = l1 - l2 - w2
t = t2 - t1 - h1
w = w1 + w2
h = h1 + h2
```

The following is a short javascript demo to show this in action. You can drag any of the two rectangles. They will change color when overlapping

Demo: http://jsbin.com/afojes/2/

Code: http://jsbin.com/afojes/2/edit

[image: No collision]

[image: Collision detected]

Comment: I suspected it was something simple, but not as simple as this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention how awesome you are for creating the js demo. Everyone reading this answer should +1 you just for that.

Comment: Fast (and simple) for humans to do, often means fast for a machine to do. Since we need something very fast for collision, we can expect that it should be simple xD

Comment: I have a feeling that this Javascript example is wrong since ths Y axis on that page is inverted. Even using Minkowski Sums by flipping one of the boxes gets me different results. But I can't proof it 100% wrong, maybe someone with more expirience than me wants to verify that. Right now this is the only source for example calculations I could find so I have nothing else to test my implementation against.

Comment: I agree with Chris. The top and bottom sides are inverted in that javascript example. At least as far as my knowledge about Minkowski difference goes. The collision detection still works though, because the way it is done, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: While this code is helpful, it appears to be incorrect.I have manipulated the rects in the first demo such that there is a visible gap between them, yet still they are coloured red and the collision condition is reported as true. The figures displayed inside them are: "box1: 10,60,160,180" and "box2: 160,172,330,312" and at the top, "collision: true. minkowski: -320,8,0,252", yet screen-shotting the canvas and looking with one's favourite image editor reveals there to be a 2x8 pixel gap between them. :eek:!